# Returning rvalue reference from a function that returns Boost optional

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, move-semantics, boost-optional

As of Boost 1.56, Boost optional supports move semantics. In that case, is the following construct meaningful?

```
boost::optional<SomeType> getValue()
{
  if (value_available) {       // value_available is a boolean
    return std::move(value);   // value is of type SomeType
  } else {
    return boost::none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be meaningful. It means you move from `value` in case you have it.

However, it surprises me that you *return as* optional, when it appears that *semantically* the class already contains an optional value (`value_available` is the indicator of that).

So, instead I'd suggest to store `value` as `optional<T>` already and *just* return that

```
return value; // already optional!
```

In this case you get proper move semantics and RVO for free. Of course if `value` is not a local or temporary, you need to say

```
return std::move(value);
```

> (Sidenote: I don't agree with the other answer that this is *only* useful if `getValue()` is called only once. If your type has a well-defined "default" state to return to after move, then it could become a sort of "1-element queue".)
>
> In such a case it might be nice to explicitly uninitialize the source value before returning. I think it is tricky to implement this exchange in an exception safe way though.
>
> Consider renaming the function to e.g. `popValue()`, `extractValue()` or `consume()` to explicitly mention the fact that using this function moves from internal object state. Of course, some warning is already implicitly present in the fact that the member function is not `const` but good naming is important too

Answer (score 1):

It would only be meaningful if you only need to call `getValue()` once, or if ownsership transfer semantics apply, as it destroys `value` after the first call.

Comment: So if value were local to the getValue function, then it would make sense.

Comment: @CppNoob In that case, the compiler will probably elide the copy anyway by RVO.

Comment: @MikeSeymour how would there be RVO since the type doesn't even match? There will always be the implicit construction of an optional. I think I get what you're referring to (don't "spell" out `std::move` on returns) but in this is case it's about spelling out the move-construction of the optional